# The past is never dead. It's not even past.

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, history

<sub>This is an entry in the [14th Fortnightly Topic Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/fortnightly-topic-challenge-14-history).</sub>

---

We thought it was dead. We were wrong. The past history has risen again; it has taken over the present -- it has *messed with* the present, even with me. Now all we see is utter *confusion and disorder.*

We don't want what is past. The present is much more important -- *each and every second of it, for they spell out how the future will be*.

The responsibility is upon you, reader. Can you clean up the mess and predict the fate of future earth?

> It had animals.
>
> Too yoked.
>
> Royal time.
>
> I inhabit poesy Asia.
>
> Bing-king jeep.
>
> A re-aspirin.

Regards,

Step-parents.

Comment: Why there are disappearing dollar signs in the title? Bug?

Comment: @mariadeleva it is Mathjax, usually used to display math formulas.  Not sure why the periods are formatted as in line formulas.  Quick Mathjax tutorial can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I couldn't make the period appear normally (periods at the end of a title is not allowed I guess?), so the Mathjax.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As noted in [@Peszo's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41491/25412),

> Every line contains an anagram of the old and the new name of a country or city.

They have been jointly solved by @Peszo, @Gamow, and @MariaDeleva in [that answer.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41491/25412)

It remains to predict the fate of future earth.

The fate of future earth is

> given by each and every second letter of the clues which are in the "present" time. Refer to clue "We don't want what is past. The present is much more important -- each and every second of it, for they spell out how the future will be."

The clues were

> T**H**AILAND
>  T**O**KYO
>  I**T**ALY
>  E**T**HIOPIA
>  B**E**IJING
>  I**R**AN

Therefore the future earth is going to be

> HOTTER

Comment: Peking/Beijing are not old and new names of the same city. They're old and new transliterations into English of the _same_ city name.

Comment: Equally, while the Roman Empire encompassed all of modern Italy, it encompassed much more besides. I doubt that the Romans thought of what we recognise today as Italy as their 'country' in any meaningful sense. But why let that get in the way of a good quiz! :-)

Answer (score 28):

Answer:

> Every line contains an anagram of the old and the new name of a country or city.

Individual answers:

> * "It had animals" is an anagram of "Siam Thailand".
>  * "Too yoked" is an anagram of "Edo Tokyo".
>  * "Royal time" is an anagram of "Rome Italy".
>  * "I inhabit poesy Asia" is an anagram of "Abyssinia Ethiopia".
>  * "Bing-king jeep" is an anagram of "Peking Beijing".
>  * "A re-aspirin" is an anagram of "Persia Iran".

Comment: Royal time - Rome Italy

Comment: I think this is still a partial answer as it doesn't yet "predict the fate of future earth"

Comment: If I've worked it out, do I add a separate answer or edit this?

Comment: @bg6471 Add a separate answer, since this one is not fully answering the puzzle.

Comment: It seems worth pointing out explicitly that "Step-parents" is an anagram of "Past-present".